# Making s3 secure when presigning upload

Tags: amazon-s3, object-storage

I have been trying to get S3 storage implemented in my web application. However I have reached a point where I deadlock myself.

I am using presigned url.

User gets presigned url, uploads a file and the url now has to be sent back for saving in the backend. Which will then move it.

What’s the most logical way of making sure the user doesn’t Just guess another url, send it in a request and thus get that file signed and downloaded instead of the file he should have gotten?
This way he can get access to private files.

Answer (score 0):

If your user can guess a url from your service, and you return a pre-signed version of that url, then pre-signing is basically pointless.

If the user is only allowed to access *some* objects, then your system should make sure you're only ever returning pre-signed urls for the objects that user has access to.

Comment: So if person 1 uploads personal document. Then person 2 who only have access to upload images figures out the naming scheme of the key. He could brute force a key into his image saving request and get it signed for download and get person 1 document (if private image download request). So the only way to prevent this is to make the key impossible/complex enough? So instead of “{guid}.ext” something like “{random 15 chars}_{filename}.ext”. Still possible but might take a few years. Or any way to prevent this?

Comment: No, your application has a function that generates a signature for a specific file. That  signature will only be valid for that specific file. Your application should never return a signed url for a file that a user shouldn't access.

Comment: So, this is a business logic thing. `if (canAccessFile(file, user) signUrl` really simply put. Don't give users signed urls unless they *should* get them

Comment: Yes but imagine user is making a blog post, which involves uploading an arbitrary file to s3. The key has to be saved back to the blog entity, there’s no way to check if user has access to the file he uploaded unless I look at the path if it involves the user id. Else he can change the key and add that to the blog entity, as I have no other way to trust that the incoming key can be signed for download later ( if I let all uploads to “/temp” and move when added to the blog )

Comment: My issue is trusting the key that the frontend sends back is the actual one that it uploaded and not an existing it’s trying to get access to

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/9JMFwtC 
Here i drew a bit, what i am afraid of is that in nr. 4, i could send any key and get it signed when reloading data - thus getting access to a file i should not.

Comment: I guess what I'm trying to explain is, if the user requests an object to be signed with a specific key. It's up to _you_ to determine that this current user is actually allowed to access this key. If user 1 is allowed to access Key A, B and C, it's up to your web application to prevent the user from getting a signature for Key D.

How that is done, is up to you. Perhaps you need a database that has a list of users with which keys they have access to.